# How to print values which are parallel to the values In another column?

Tags: java, android

i used retrofit android With a database server ,
The problem is I have a database on localhost 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdhOQ.png
I want to create a array So that only within it values 
Which is next to the value of the number 8
So that the arrayString contains makarona and asd without Other values
but here it is print makarona and asd  and null 
i want a array with the corresponding names of number 8
See the code to see arrayString And tried to correct me the code

```
private void getAllMeal(final int id_) {
        api = HttpApi.getInstance();
        api.addHeader("Authorization", "MyT23");
        // Get iteme from index number .....
        getUsersCall = api.getService().getAllChatRooms4();
        ///----------------------------
        getUsersCall.enqueue(new retrofit.Callback<List<Users>>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit.Response<List<Users>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                user = response.body();

                String [] arrayString = new String[user.size()];
                int[] arrayInt = new int[user.size()];

                for(int i=0; i<response.body().size(); i++) {
                  arrayInt[i] = user.get(i).fk_chef;
                    if(Arrays.asList(arrayInt).contains(id_)){
                        arrayString[i] = user.get(i).name;
                    }
                  Toast.makeText(chef_hello.this,"results names  :"+arrayString[i],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                //dialog2.dismiss();
                //Toast.makeText(chef_hello.this,"Error  Throwable xx :",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Toast.makeText(Regest_login.this, "XXX", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to connect to Mysql using http ?